# Constraint Programming with Python

Tags: python, constraint-programming

I'm trying to write a simple script to solve a CSP. I'm currently using python-constraint https://github.com/DanielCasner/python-constraint.

But I want to add a constraint over two specific variables in the problem. Is this possible? For instance, variable a and b should sum to 5.

Thanks!

Comment: This is almost identical to one of the first examples on the homepage: `problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b: a*2 == b, ("a", "b")`. The only difference is that you want `a+b == 5` instead of `a*2 == b`. (Or you could use an `ExactSumConstraint` instead of writing a function.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just provide a list of what variable names the constraint applies to as the `variables` optional argument to `addConstraint`.